# Setting Accept-Language in COM-embedded IE

Tags: c, internet-explorer, com

I have an IE instance embedded in my C application using COM. With IWebBrowser2.Navigate I can pass headers to be sent along with the request, except apparently "Accept-Language". It seems the language settings from IE itself always override the value I pass in for that header. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think IE allows you to customize the settings so much. Never used it in C, but Delphi has a wrapper class to IWebBrowser2 (TWebBrowser), and most settings used by the component are global. I mean, the same for standard IE and embedded IE.

Maybe you can change it on Internet Options or even modify some registry keys, but be aware that it will also apply globally (embedded or not).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried callling [SetThreadLocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374051.aspx)? Maybe IE ignores the header in favor of the user's language settings.

Comment: A reasonable suggestion, but no, IE doesn't try to guess from the Thread Locale.